# Contradiction Proof, proving a vertex coloured graph of $n$ colours cannot have a subgraph $K_{n+1}$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

A graph $G$ can be vertex coloured with $n$ colours if it is possible to assign one of $n$ different colours to the vertices of $G$, such that no two adjacent vertices have the same colour. Prove that if $G$ can be vertex coloured with $n$ colours, then $K_{n+1}$ is not a subgraph of $G$.

In particular, I'm interested in solving this using contradiction, since I have been shown a different way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $K_n$ is a clique of size $|K_n|=n=\omega(K_n)$.

Trivially, for the chromatic number of a graph $G$ it holds that $\omega(G) \leq \chi(G)$, since all vertices in a maximum clique are pairwise adjacent, thus we need at least $\omega(G)$ colours to colour $G$.

Assume that $\chi(G)=n$, then $\omega(G)\leq n$. But a $K_{n+1}$ has $\omega(K_{n+1})=n+1$ by definition. Assume that $G$ contains $K_{n+1}$ as a subgraph, then $n+1=|K_{n+1}| \leq \omega(G)$, but $\omega(G) \leq n$. A contradiction.

**Edit**

I would like to provide some more details in response to the questions given in the comments.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple, undirected graph. A subset $X \subseteq V$ is called a clique in $G$ if all vertices in $X$ are pairwise adjacent. A clique is called maximal clique if we can not add any vertex $x \in V \setminus X$ to $X$ such that $x$ is adjacent to all the other vertices in $X$.

A clique $X$ in $G$ is called maximum clique if there is no other clique $Y$ in $G$ such that $|X| < |Y|$.

**Example**

Consider the following graph. Let us call it $G$.

[image]

The vertex set $\{1,3\}$ is a maximal clique in $G$. We can not add any other vertex $x$ such that $x$ is adjacent to $1$ and $3$.

However, this is not the maximum clique in $G$ because the set $\{2,3,4\}$ is a clique as well but with greater cardinality. It is easy to see that this is the maximum clique of $G$.

We call the cardinality of a maximum clique in $G$ the clique number of $G$ and denote it by $\omega(G)$.

The chromatic number on the other hand is the minimum number of colours needed in order to colour the vertices of $G$ such that no adjacent vertices share the same colour. We denote this number by $\chi(G)$.

Now, take a look at the maximum clique of the graph given above. Let us colour the vertex $2$ with red. Can we colour $4$ or $3$ red? No because they are adjacent to $2$. Let us therefore colour vertex $4$ green. Can we colour vertex $3$ green? No, because it is adjacent to $4$. Let us colour $3$ yellow. We already needed three colours for colouring $G$. It is easy to see that if the maximum clique would have four vertices, then we would have needed at least one more colour.

It is tempting to think that the chromatic number and the clique number coincide. This is not the case!

Consider the following graph.

[image]

The chromatic number is $3$ (convince yourself that this is true as an exercise). However, it is easy to see that the clique number is $2$.

In general we can combine the above observations by saying $\omega(G) \leq \chi(G)$. This is a trivial observation and the above explanations should be sufficient to be convincing.

A complete graph is a graph $G=(V, E)$ such that all vertices in $G$ are pairwise adjacent. We denote a complete graph on $n$ vertices by $K_n$. It should be clear that a complete graph is identical to the definition of a clique. Why two different names for the same thing? This is not used consistently in literature, however in my personal experience we usually use the name clique when we want to emphasize that we are talking about an induced subgraph of a given graph such that all vertices in that induced subgraph are adjacent. In particular when we are dealing with the graph colouring problem.

When talking about a complete graph $K_n$ on $n$ vertices then the maximum clique in $K_n$ is obviously $K_n$ itself. Therefore a complete graph on $n+1$ vertices has clique number $n+1$. This follows directly from the definition.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I follow, you said, that trivially the chromatic number of the graph will have ω(G)≤χ(G), can you elaborate on why we can make this assumption? 
And secondly, you said, K_(n+1) has ω(K_(n+1))=n+1 by definition, what allows you to assume this also?

Comment: I added more details. Do not hesitate to ask more. I am happy to answer them.